# No Fancybox captions (title) showing up

Tags: jquery, fancybox, picasa

I'm using the PWI (Picasa Web Integrator) with fancybox.  I'm trying to get the latest version of fancybox 2.1.4 working with it along with jquery 1.91, and have, but just can't get the captions/title to show.

I've tried a lot of things, looking at JS fiddles and also on here from other answers, but it will not show up.

I've checked in developer mode and see the  reference, correctly with titles...and have recently added the class"fancybox" attribute too, but to no avail.

I'm stumped (I'm also a novice)...

Please check here if you have a bit of time and allow me to sleeeeep!

http://www.talesfromthesaddle.com/picasa9/photos.shtml

Comment: From a quick view, in this file http://www.talesfromthesaddle.com/picasa9/js/jquery.pwi.js you have this function `formatPhotoTitleFancyBox()` that is creating the issue ... you also have (in the same file) this `this.title = $(this.element).attr('title');}` out of context

Comment: Yeah, I was actually just looking at that.  Which actually accounts for the out of place `this.title = $(this.element).attr.('title');`

But, I can now look into `formatPhotoTitleFancyBox()` some more knowing that's where the problem is, thanks JFK :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Just needed to change the beforeLoad call of `formatPhotoTitleFancyBox()` to "onLoad".

Thanks to JFK for taking time to look, and for keeping me looking in the right spot.